# Find what gmail account is associated to a known Analytics tracking code?

Tags: seo

A client of ours created a Google Analytics account by himself in july 2013 and asked us to introduce the code to their site. Recently they asked for the data but we obvioulsy don´t have access to it and he don´t remember what email account he created it from.

We have replaced the old UA with a new one managed by us, but it occurred to me perhaps we could somehow find out what gmail adress the original UA code was associated with in order to recover the old traffic data. Here is the original code: UA-42583725-1 and here´s the current one (the one we DO have access to): UA-49424805-1

We have FTP access to site in case you need us to prove we are the owners of the site.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Can you contact the client to ask them which account they used, and even if they could add your account as an admin? (By the way, this should be posted to Webmasters (http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), as StackOverflow is for coding questions.)

Comment: They forgot the email account.. any other alternative?